# Software for downloading Android apps on Ubuntu

Tags: open-source, ubuntu

Can someone recommend an open-source application I can use to download Android apps using ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome user48339! From where do you want to download the apps?

Answer (score 1):

I use **[Raccoon](https://github.com/onyxbits/Raccoon)** for that. It's an open-source application developed in Java, so it works cross-platform.

[image]
<sup>*Raccoon* (source: [Raccoon Website](https://raccoon.onyxbits.de/); click image to enlarge)</sup>

Works pretty well, and is actively maintained. I'm using it for years already, and am quite satisfied with it.

Comment: Update 2021: Program is a Java `.jar` file which can still be [downloaded](https://raccoon.onyxbits.de/apk-downloader/). The program can be started with Java 14 , I have used the Linux command `export GDK_SCALE=3 && java -jar raccoon-4.19.0.jar`. Tune the GDK_SCALE parameter to your needs and characteristics of your high-DPI Monitor (4K and  higher)